# Maintain a class with dictionary of properties

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I need to design a class where each of the properties of the class is added and updated in an ObservableDictionary in the class itself.

Here is the code I have come up with.

```
class Win32_DiskDrive : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly string _classname = "Win32_DiskDrive";

    public string ClassName
    {
        get
        {
            return _classname;
        }
    }

    private string _caption;

    public string Caption
    {
        get
        {
            return _caption;
        }

        set
        {
            if ((value != _caption) || (value != null))
            {
                _caption = value;
                UpdateDictionary();
                OnPropertyChange();
            }                
        }
    }        

    private string _serialNo;

    public string SerialNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _serialNo;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != _serialNo) || (value != null))
            {
                _serialNo = value;
                UpdateDictionary();
                OnPropertyChange();
            }
        }
    }

    private IDictionary<string,string> _diskDriveProperties = new ObservableDictionary<String, String>();

    public IDictionary<string, string> PropertiesDictionary
    {
        get
        {
            return _diskDriveProperties;
        }

        private set
        {
            _diskDriveProperties = value;
        }                        
    }

    private void UpdateDictionary([CallerMemberName] string propertyname = null)
    {
        _diskDriveProperties[propertyname] = this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyname).GetValue(this).ToString();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string propertyname = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }
}
```

Is there a way to implement this class without reflection by using Linq?

Comment: Why not just pass the new value to the `UpdateDictionary` method? That would make everything rather simpler...

Comment: Actually, I have several classes with several properties like these, almost as many classes as there are in WMI. This approach makes it rather easier to keep it simple for testing.

Comment: Would changing `UpdateDictionary();` to `UpdateDictionary(value);` really make it so much harder?

Comment: Oh, extremely sorry. Somehow, in my sleep-deprived state, I mistook what you said for something like this: `_diskDriveProperties[foo] = value` where foo is the property name in each setter. Your solution is much more intuitive. Thank you.